# It is possible to force an executable to use an user defined 'malloc'?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, compilation, linker

I want to understand how memory tracker and leak detector work, so I come with this idea, I have an executable, and I want to force it while execution to use my own memory allocation functions instead of the usual system functions ("malloc", "realloc"...).

My own functions are stored in a library (static or shared) or just an object file (".o"), thik about something like that:

```
void *my_own_malloc(unsigned long size) {
     printf("allocate: %lu\n", size);
     return malloc(size);
}
```

PS: I don't have to change the executable source code (I don't have source code)

PS2: I want to do that in all different platform (Windows, OS X & Linux...)

Comment: @Lolrapa The problem here is that the injected function must have the some name as 'malloc', but inside the injected function there are an invocation to the system "malloc", that will maybe produce an infinite recursive function?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the other platforms, but on GNU/Linux you could pre-load a small memory tracking library with the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable in which your own `malloc` and `free` are defined.

Your own `malloc` would probably want to allocate memory using the real `malloc` function, so there's a possible recursive problem here. To work around this, the [dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) function can use an `RTLD_NEXT` argument to obtain the pointer to the next (i.e. the 'real') `malloc` function.

A very small test of this could look like the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    static void *(*real_malloc)(size_t size) = 0;

    if (!real_malloc)
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    void *result = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%d) = %p\n", (int)size, result);
    return result;
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    static void (*real_free)(void *ptr) = 0;
    if (!real_free)
        real_free = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");

    real_free(ptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "free(%p)\n", ptr);
}
```

If we call this file `fakemalloc.c`, it can be compiled into a `fakemalloc.so` shared object with the command

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,fakemalloc.so -o fakemalloc.so fakemalloc.c -ldl
```

As a test, to see which `malloc` and `free` calls happen in a call to the `ls` command, you'd need to execute

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/fakemalloc.so ls
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned in a comment, on glibc-systems you can avoid the `RTLD_NEXT` approach by using the functions `__libc_malloc` and `__libc_free`. This would produce the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *__libc_malloc(size_t size);
void *__libc_free(void *ptr);

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *result = __libc_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%d) = %p\n", (int)size, result);
    return result;
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    __libc_free(ptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "free(%p)\n", ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mush! `LD_PRELOAD`is all what a need, build steps are also useful. `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` may be the equivalent in OS X.

Comment: On glibc-based systems, you can also call the system malloc by calling `__libc_malloc` in your replacement malloc routines (don't need the `RTLD_NEXT` trick)

Comment: maybe print the message bevore a potentially undefined behavior, like calling free() and flush the result if it is not already by the newline (when stderr is a real file?)